# my webassembly chess ai project doesnt run on python

Tags: python, webassembly, wasmtime

I have a chess ai project I have written in c++ and compiled it to webasembly with emcc
then I wanted to serve it in a server as a webservice and I decided to use python wasmtime library for it
when I tried to run it gives some errors

```
TIME=1import wasmtime

# Create an engine
engine = wasmtime.Engine()

# Create a store
store = wasmtime.Store(engine)

# Load the Wasm module
module = wasmtime.Module(store.engine, open("c.wasm","rb").read())
imports = {
    "Module": {
        "_calcStartConstant": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([], [wasmtime.ValType.i32()]), "_calcStartConstant"),
        "_set_side": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32()], []), "_set_side"),
        "_set_piecePoints": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32(), wasmtime.ValType.i32(), wasmtime.ValType.i32(), wasmtime.ValType.i32(), wasmtime.ValType.i32(), wasmtime.ValType.i32()], []), "_set_piecePoints"),
        "_set_depth": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32()], []), "_set_depth"),
        "_next": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([], []), "_next"),
        "_prev": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([], []), "_prev"),
        "_selectBest": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32()], [wasmtime.ValType.i32()]), "_selectBest"),
        "_set_Coefs": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32(), wasmtime.ValType.f32()], []), "_set_Coefs"),
        "_set_time_limit": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32()], []), "_set_time_limit"),
        "_malloc": wasmtime.Func(store, wasmtime.FuncType([wasmtime.ValType.i32()],[wasmtime.ValType.i32()]), "_malloc")
    }
}
# Instantiate the module
instance = wasmtime.Instance(store,module, imports) 

# Access functions and memory of the module as needed
# For example, to call a function named "_selectBest":
_selectBest = instance.exports.get_func("_selectBest")

# Provide the string argument and get the result
argument = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"
result_ptr = _selectBest.call(argument)
if result_ptr:
    result = wasmtime.ffi.string(result_ptr).decode()
    wasmtime.ffi.wasmtime_externref_delete(result_ptr)
    print(result)
else:
    print("Error occurred while calling _selectBest function")
result = wasmtime.ffi.string(result_ptr).decode()

# Handle the result as required
print(result)
```

it gives that error

TypeError: expected a Func, Global, Memory, Table, Module, or Instance

what can cause it, please help

I want that the code runs and my webassembly file calculates for the best move at the game begining then says the result

Comment: There are a few things you can do, to help us with debugging the error: 1. Create a minimum viable proof of concept. Can you make a program with just a simple function, maybe the one that gets the game as a string, and try to call that, and see the errors? 2. Include the full errors and how you compile the project (maybe the sources for the proof of concept here). 3. Emscripten is mostly for the web, you can also try your luck at other project, like wasi-sdk https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk#notable-limitations, with this caveat about C++ limitations.